# Where are page views coming from?

Tags: discussion

In the past two days [one of my questions from last year](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/390708/) has received over 8,000 views. I am curious about what might have caused the sudden burst of interest in this old question.

Google search for links to the question does not produce anything, and the SE Data explorer seems not to expose any information about referring URLs.

Does anyone have any suggestions about how to investigate this?

Comment: @anorton Here's a [direct link](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/390708/), and also [link to the timeline](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/390708/timeline) for those interested.

Comment: It's just me looking at it over and over again. Sorry.

Answer (score 9):

I posted a link to this question on [reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/2aka8p/proof_that_pipipipi_is_a_noninteger/), and it was somewhat well-received. It's worth mentioning that there's quite a lot of posts from MSE on /r/math, and it's not at all unusual for them to receive a couple thousand views.

Comment: Well-received enough for  your [10th Publicist badge](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/61/publicist?userid=61527). I wonder if one could do reverse-lookup for this badge: from question to the user who earned a badge for it...

Comment: Thanks very much!

Comment: While this answers the question of where the page views are coming from, it doesn't help with the more general question of “how do I investigate this” unless the answer is “post to meta”. In the future I will remember to check Reddit, though.

Comment: @This: One who is not badge thirsty can implicate others (or bequeath others) by using reference links with other users' ID.

Answer (score 5):

Although SEDE contains the table Badges, it does not at present associate badges with posts. I made a feature request [Add Post Id to Badges table when applicable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/236582/) which, if fulfilled, will allow one to look up promotion-based badges for any particular post.

For now, one can browse the lists of posts for which promotional badges were awarded. The [Publicist](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/61/publicist)  list is quite short at present; [Booster](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/60/booster) is still under 100. [Announcer](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/59/announcer) would take a while to browse, but that badge can account for at most 25 visits.

If the post wasn't shared using the site-generated *share* link with user's Id at the end, then  Google search is probably the best option.

Comment: (Note that this is not foolproof, and one can easily use someone else's user ID.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, but this would still (kind of) answer the question "where the views come from". "Who posted that" is a different question.

Comment: Uhh, telling you who got a badge for sharing a link doesn't tell you where the link was shared. For all you know it was placed in a QR code on a billboard in downtown LA.

Comment: Now I wonder if that would cause SE to crash...

Comment: @AsafKaragila There aren't enough people in LA, I think. According to [Nick Craver](http://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/11/22/what-it-takes-to-run-stack-overflow/), SE gets about 150M hits on a typical day, which translates into 6M per hour on average. (In fact more because the traffic is not evenly distributed throughout the day.) Nick Craver also notes that their 11 web servers run at low utilization, and having just 2 of them would suffice to serve all those requests. They have pretty good equipment in the [data center](https://twitter.com/hashtag/stackdcmove).

Comment: Fine, Hong Kong+Tokyo+Times Square?